# Extra Comma at the end of the string

Tags: apex, email-template, string

I want to generate the string as `number1, number2, number3` with the following code.

```
    String accountNumbers = '';
    for(Account Acc: solvAccounts){
        accountNumbers = accountNumbers + '' + Acc.Name + ', ';
    }
    accountNumbers.replace(',','');
```

But the output I am getting is `number1, number2, number3,`. need help to remove the extra comma at the end of the string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For such purposes I recommend you to use [`String.join()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) method, which joins the elements of the specified iterable object, such as a List, into a single String separated by the specified separator:

```java
List<String> accNames = new List<String>();
for (Account acc : solvAccounts) {
    accNames.add(acc.Name);
}
String result = String.join(accName, ', ');
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [removeEnd(substring)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) method from String class in Apex.

```
String str = 'number1, number2, number3,';
str = str.removeEnd(',');
system.debug('Str ' + str);

Output : Str number1, number2, number3
```